# SQL Server Query to split nights spent into respective 'Month" Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, split

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I need to write a query that will split the difference between the Date of Arrival and Date of Departure (that is, number of nights spent) and post the result into its respective `Month` column.

I already know how to write the query that will fetch my Date of Arrival and Date of Departure but it is the split part that is the most difficult part for me. My end results need to look something like this:

```
ID    Name       Date of Arrival    Date of Departure   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr
203   Mr Smith   2014.02.24         2014.03.02                5    1    
455   Mr Jones   2014.04.10         2014.04.17                          7
```

The `ID`, `Name`, `Date of Arrival` and `Date of Departure` come from a specific table. How do I add the split part to my existing query so that the output looks like the above?

After doing some research, I noticed that a `Calendar` table might be of some help but I don't know how to implement this into my query.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Share some work around or the query by which your able to generate the mentioned output. On which basis you will split the data?

Comment: what if the date of the arrival is at the end of the month and the date of departure is the first of the next month, in this case the counts should go to which month?

Comment: @ Surendra Nath GM: The count would go to the month relating to the date of arrival because we are counting nights spent and not number of days spent.

Answer (score 2):

I think a Calendar table is going to be the way to go.  I think the query looks something like this, I named your table VisitDate and assumed the Calendar table has a Date field and a Month field.

```
select ID, Name, [DATEADD of Arrival], [DATEADD of Departure], 
    sum(case when c.month = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan, 
    sum(case when c.month = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb, 
    sum(case when c.month = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Mar, 
    sum(case when c.month = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as Apr 
from 
    VisitDate
    join Calendar c on c.Date >= [DATEADD of Arrival] and c.Date <= [DATEADD of Departure]
```

Comment: I'd suggest altering your query slightly to `from Calendar c left join VisitDate d on ...` mainly to then return all dates even if it doesn't even in the `VisitDate` table.

Comment: I think I need a full join because I don't care about any date that isn't part of a VisitDate, and once it is a full join it doesn't matter the order of the tables in the join.  Of course, that is assuming I understood the nature of the question correctly.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with just a set of case statements as well:
Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Booking TABLE
(
    GuestID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    ArrivalDate DATETIME,
    DepartureDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Booking
( GuestID, Name, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate )
VALUES
( 203, 'Mr Smith', '02-24-2014', '03-02-2014' ),
( 455, 'Mr Jones', '04-10-2014', '04-17-2014' ),
( 531, 'Mrs James', '07-10-2014', '09-17-2014' );
```

Going to make a calendar CTE for this year:

```
DECLARE @CheckYear INT = 2014

;WITH MonthInfo AS
(
    SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) JanStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) FebStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) MarStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) AprStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) MayStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 5, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) JunStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 6, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) JulStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 7, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) AugStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 8, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) SepStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 9, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) OctStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 10, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) NovStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 11, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1900, 0))) DecStart,
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 12, DATEADD(YEAR, @CheckYear - 1899, 0))) EOY
)
```

Now we run our query and check it against the calendar and pull out all of the overlapping dates and get the count of days

```
SELECT b.*,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.JanStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.FebStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.FebStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.FebStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JanStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JanStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.FebStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JanStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JanStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JanStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.FebStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JanStart, m.FebStart)

    ELSE 0
    END JanDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.FebStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.MarStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.MarStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.MarStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.FebStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.FebStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.MarStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.FebStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.FebStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.FebStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MarStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.FebStart, m.MarStart)

    ELSE 0
    END FebDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.MarStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.AprStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.AprStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.AprStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.MarStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MarStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.AprStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.MarStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.MarStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MarStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AprStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.MarStart, m.AprStart)
    ELSE 0
    END MarDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.AprStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.MayStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.MayStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.MarStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.AprStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AprStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.MayStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.AprStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.AprStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AprStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MayStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.AprStart, m.MayStart)

    ELSE 0
    END AprDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.MayStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.JunStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.JunStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.JunStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.MayStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MayStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.JunStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.MayStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.MayStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.MayStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JunStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.MayStart, m.JunStart)
    ELSE 0
    END MayDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.JunStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.JulStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.JulStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.JulStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JunStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JunStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.JulStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JunStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JunStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JunStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JulStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JunStart, m.JulStart)
    ELSE 0
    END JunDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.JulStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.AugStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.AugStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.AugStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JulStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JulStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.AugStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JulStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.JulStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.JulStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AugStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.JulStart, m.AugStart)
    ELSE 0
    END JulDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.AugStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.SepStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.SepStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.SepStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.AugStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AugStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.SepStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.AugStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.AugStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.AugStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.SepStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.AugStart, m.SepStart)
    ELSE 0
    END AugDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.SepStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.OctStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.OctStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.OctStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.SepStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.SepStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.OctStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.SepStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.SepStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.SepStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.OctStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.SepStart, m.OctStart)
    ELSE 0
    END SepDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.OctStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.NovStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.NovStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.NovStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.OctStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.OctStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.NovStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.OctStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.OctStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.OctStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.NovStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.OctStart, m.NovStart)
    ELSE 0
    END OctDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.NovStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.DecStart THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.DecStart THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.DecStart)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.NovStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.NovStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.DecStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.NovStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.NovStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.NovStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.DecStart THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.NovStart, m.DecStart)
    ELSE 0
    END NovDays,
    CASE WHEN b.ArrivalDate > m.DecStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.EOY THEN
        (CASE WHEN b.DepartureDate < m.EOY THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, b.DepartureDate) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ArrivalDate, m.EOY)
        END)
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.DecStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.DecStart AND b.DepartureDate < m.EOY THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.DecStart, b.DepartureDate) + 1
        WHEN b.ArrivalDate < m.DecStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.DecStart AND b.DepartureDate > m.EOY THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, m.DecStart, m.EOY)
    ELSE 0
    END DecDays
FROM @Booking b
INNER JOIN MonthInfo m
    ON b.ArrivalDate >= m.JanStart AND b.ArrivalDate < m.EOY
```

Here is the output:

```
GuestID Name    ArrivalDate DepartureDate   JanDays FebDays MarDays AprDays MayDays JunDays JulDays AugDays SepDays OctDays NovDays DecDays
203 Mr Smith    2014-02-24 00:00:00.000 2014-03-02 00:00:00.000 0   5   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
455 Mr Jones    2014-04-10 00:00:00.000 2014-04-17 00:00:00.000 0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
531 Mrs James   2014-07-10 00:00:00.000 2014-09-17 00:00:00.000 0   0   0   0   0   0   22  31  17  0   0   0
```

From the data, I had Mrs James arriving in July, staying for a couple months and then departing in September, so you can see the days overlapping the months as well.  The case statements could be turned into a function passing in the report year to make the code simpler, but I just wanted to show the way the code worked.

The alternative is to make a numbers table and create each day of the year corresponding to the dates passed:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = MIN(ArrivalDate) - 1 FROM @Booking

DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
), 

CalTable AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.number, @StartDate) CheckDate
    FROM numbers n
)
```

Then just sum on the months:

```
SELECT b.GuestID,
    b.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JanDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FebDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MarDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AprDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MayDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JunDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JulDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AugDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SepDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OctDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NovDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.CheckDate) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DecDays
FROM CalTable c
INNER JOIN @Booking b
    ON c.CheckDate BETWEEN b.ArrivalDate AND b.DepartureDate
GROUP BY b.GuestID, b.Name
```

Here is the output:

```
GuestID Name    JanDays FebDays MarDays AprDays MayDays JunDays JulDays AugDays SepDays OctDays NovDays DecDays
455 Mr Jones    0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
203 Mr Smith    0   5   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
531 Mrs James   0   0   0   0   0   0   22  31  17  0   0   0
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your effort in providing an answer! I highly appreciate it. In the second alternative you provide, the output is in terms of days rather than nights. May I ask how I adjust for that in your codes?

Comment: Rather than use between (inclusive), just use c.CheckDate >= b.ArrivalDate AND c.CheckDate < b.DepartureDate and that should just pull nights stayed.